# Highcharter R package : prevent zoom event on chart after making drag Selection

Tags: javascript, r, json, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to make a drag selection on columns without zooming.
I know that highcharter package in R uses javascript highcharts wrapper, so I tried to apply javascript highcharts logic in R but it doesn't seem to work.
I also know that I have to use "event.preventDefault()" to prevent the zoom option in highcharts, But I don't know how to use it in R.
This is what my code looks like:

```
 library(shiny)
 library(highcharter)
 data("citytemp")

 hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type="column",
           event= list(
             selection = JS(
               "function selectPointsByDrag(e) {

                 // Select points
                 Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
                   Highcharts.each(series.points, function (point) {
                     if (point.x >= e.xAxis[0].min && point.x <= e.xAxis[0].max &&
                         point.y >= e.yAxis[0].min && point.y <= e.yAxis[0].max) {
                       point.select(true, true);
                     }
                   });
                 });

                 // Fire a custom event
                 Highcharts.fireEvent(this, 'selectedpoints', { points: this.getSelectedPoints() });

                 return false; // Don't zoom
               }"
             )
           ),
           zoomType= "xy") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      borderWidth=0,
      dataLabels=list(enabled=TRUE),
      allowPointSelect= TRUE
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) 
hc
```

Please help me, I've tried everything!

Comment: You have a typo in your code - line 7 events, not event. Your code is working fine. Let me know if this was an issue.

Comment: Yes it's working, but not the way I want..what I want is to select columns through drag selection with the zoom disabled.

Comment: And your code is just doing it. Am I missing something? I will fire your code tomorrow and double check, but I remember that 3 days ago I was able to select points without zooming. Your function in chart.events.selection is working fine.